# How to compile Greta against VES2008?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I compiled Greta against VES2008, it reports

```
error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name                                           
error C3306: 'regex::detail::<unnamed-tag>': unnamed class template is not allowed
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__builtin_alignof'                
error C2059: syntax error : '__builtin_alignof'                                   
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'                                
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

relevant source code snippet:

```
template< typename T >
class alignof
{
    struct helper
    {
        helper();
        char    m_c;
        T       m_t;
    };
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(helper)-sizeof(T) < sizeof(T) ? sizeof(helper)-sizeof(T) : sizeof(T) };
};
```

after precompiled, it

```
template< typename T >
class __alignof
{
    struct helper
    {
        helper();
        char    m_c;
        T       m_t;
    };
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(helper)-sizeof(T) < sizeof(T) ? sizeof(helper)-sizeof(T) : sizeof(T) };
};
```

I have not found answers after googling. what caused this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `alignof` does not seem to be a reserved word in VS2008, it's so similar to [`_alignof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45t0s5f4.aspx) that it may be confusing the issue.

Try changing the name of your class to something different.

Comment: yes, thanks; I find the problem it because I introduced the 3rd lib which contains one line #define alignof  __alignof
that's the root cause, thanks again